# How to disable the Character Viewer in Big Sur?

Tags: macbook-pro, shortcut, keybindings, big-sur, shortcut-menu

How should I change shortcut or disable emoji menu by `ctrl`+`cmd`+`space`. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Do you just want to disable the shortcut or do you want to use it for something else?

Comment: @nohillside I would like to deactivate this first and then use it in Intellij idea. Any idea how should I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How should I change shortcut or disable emoji menu by ctrl+cmd+space. Is it possible?

Yes, it's possible, and you can change the default *keyboard shortcut* to something else in: **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **App Shortcuts**

Click the [+] *button* and in the *sheet* that appears...

- Set **Application:** to: **All Applications**
- Set **Menu Title:** to: **Emoji & Symbols**

  - Use the actual menu title as it shows on the **Edit** menu on the menu bar, based on your **Language & Region** *settings*. In this example it's **English**.
- Set **Keyboard Shortcut** to e.g.: **⌃⇧⌘Space**

  - After setting focus to it, press the *keyboard shortcut* you'd like to use. Once you've pressed the *keys*, click the **Add** *button*.

<sub>**Note**: Assigning global shortcuts can be problematic, and you'll need to use a *keyboard shortcut* that is not already assigned in whatever *application* has focus when pressing the new *keyboard shortcut*.</sub>

[image: System Preferences]

Comment: broo... thank you very much <3 
this feature was annoying for me

Answer (score 4):

Following solution work on big sur.

`System Preference > Keyboard > Keyboard`

There must be a flag with this label "Press  to ".
In the drop down next to this label, Just select `Do Nothing`

Comment: Your answer doesn't address the question, which is how to disable the keyboard shortcut control command space.

Comment: I think the question was "How should I change shortcut or disable emoji menu"

Comment: Although this may not have explicitly solved the question posted it helped me find what I was looking for :) Cheers.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for as well. Thanks @Shreyansh Panchal!

Comment: Why was this so hard to find!

Answer (score -2):

This is Character Viewer.

This is very handy tool for entering special characters. In order to get rid of emojis one can change settings:

- click on on icon upper right.

[image]

This will open expanded view.

- click on down arrow icon left upper.

[image]

Dropdown menu will be displayed.

- click on 'Customize list'

[image]

'Select categories' window will open

- Select/Deselect needed categories and click 'Done'

[image]

- Switch back to compact view using icon on upper right corner

Character Viewer 'remembers' you choice and your sceenshot indicates that you have selected 'emoji' menu as default (have look at the footer on your screenshot). If you want display 'Frequently Used' and 'Favorites' by default (like on my screenshots) click on clock icon in footer (leftmost). Next time you invoke Character Viewer it opens there.

Comment: How does this answer "How should I change shortcut or disable emoji menu "?

Comment: This effectively disables emoji menu. But it will not disable Character Viewer shortcut but this was not the question as far as I understood (and yes,  I am not english native :-)).

Comment: thank you for your time, but I need to rebind shortcut or just disable this menu